# Uninstalling KB3020369

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I am using a brand new embedded system that runs Windows 7, and it has spontaneously installed the Update KB3020369.

I'd like to get rid of it as it is eating up precious disk space, but the standard procedures (via the control panel or the *wusa* command) do not work. You get the message 'Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3020369) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled'.

Do you have a solution ? (I found many posts on the topic on the Web but non was conclusive so far.)

Comment: have you tried wusa /uninstall /kb: 3020369 /quiet /forcestart

Else do system restore. However this is not a solution to your systems performance

Comment: The Update does not appear in the restore list. The Update does appear in the Control Panel, but there is no Uninstall option. MS made that on purpose.

Comment: Windows System restore will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (officially) uninstall this update, because it is marked as permanent in its manifest file (metadata)

```
<package identifier="KB3020369" [...] permanence="permanent">
```

Microsoft does this for all [servicing stack](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx) updates. You could remove this permanence entry, but I had issues in the past after removing older servicing stack updates. So don't try this.

What do you mean with eating up space? run [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) to see which folder uses most space.

Comment: I mean that free space decreased by 1 to 2 GB after the install, which is significant in my context.

Comment: I tried to find this entry in a manifest file, to no avail.

Comment: if you run the tool as admin, you may see that **System Volume Information** has growm. This is the location of the system restore points. So delete older ones: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/delete-restore-point#1TC=windows-7